# Search with Array of Ids

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, search, activerecord

So let's say I have Two Model Post & Category.

```
Post has_many Categories
```

Now,I want to search Post based on category?

Example:

```
Post 1 has categories 2,5,6

Post 2 has categories 5,9

Post 3 has categories 2,4,8,9
```

Now In search User Select categories 2,4,8

In Result page I want to display the Post wich has  categories(2,4,8)

**Post 3**

But when we use IN  query that return both Post 1 & post 3.

I want only Post 3

Comment: Come on, you can do better. It's important you to demonstrate some work before asking for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
categories_ids=[2,3,4]

@posts = Post.joins(:categories).
  where("categories.id IN (?) ",categories_ids).count(:group => "post_id")
```

The result Will be like this:

```
{"1"=>2,"3"=>2}
```

in that Hash key define the Post id & value define the Number of Category matched .

Answer (score 0):

```
category_ids = [2,4,8]
Post.select('posts.*')
     joins(:categories).
     where(categories: {id: category_ids}).
     group('posts.id').
     having('COUNT(categories.id) = ?', category_ids.size)
```